# updated a document with express

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I'm trying to use the mongoDB and update the status of a current document. My backend is receiving the routes my mongoDB update isn't going through.

```
router.post('/orders_drivers', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    Order.update({_id:objectId(req.body.id)}, {$set: {driver:req.body.driver, driverReq:false}}).then (function (order) {
        console.log('UPDATE new driver');
    }).catch (next)
});
```

when I log the req.body, the ID I receive and the new `$set` parameters are correct, but the command never goes through. Any suggestions? I don't receive any errors either which I think is strange.

Mongo version is v4.0.2

I have many other routes that all work correctly.

Comment: Are you using the correct collection name? collection names may be case sensitive.

Comment: What is the version of your mongodb driver?
Are you using the native library?

Comment: You should try ".catch( (err) => { console.log(err) })".  This might help you to got the actual error.

Comment: please specify the version of MongoDB driver. are you using mongoose?

Comment: I have added more detail's. I have other routes that talk to the same collection and it works great. The version v4.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no version issue. you are calling then function on **non promiseable** value.

You need to call a **callback** function inside of update.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.post('/orders_drivers', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    Order.update({
                  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id)
                 },
                 {
                  $set: {
                     driver:req.body.driver, driverReq:false
                  }
                 }, 
                 { new: true }, // If you want to return updated order
                 function (err, updatedOrder) { 
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('UPDATE new driver', updatedOrder);
                })
});
```

You don't need to convert req.body.id into mongoose ObjectId if it already is.